# Function needs to accept multiple types in one input parameter

Tags: function, rust, types

I'm working in rust to make a program that will automatically solve chemical equations (and other related things) for me. Long story short I asked my chemistry teacher if he would let me do that and use it on homework, and he said yes, as long as I wrote it myself.
I've been looking at the rust language for a while now, and I figured this would be as good a time as any to learn.
So in my project I have a struct defined as so:

```
pub struct Element<> {
    pub count: i32,
    pub name: String
}
```

and a function to build an Element defined as so:

```
pub fn element(count: i32, name:String) -> Element<> {
    let equ: Element = Element { count: count, name: name };
    return equ
}
```

This is all fine and dandy, but a frustration arose as I started doing unit tests; strings created like so:
`let xyz = "xyz"`
are &str by default. This meant that I had to type .to_string() after every single manually defined string (which I do a lot in my unit tests). As a progammer, minor inconvinience that will take longer to automate than to deal with manually is my bane (as I'm sure you all know), so I tried redefining the function like so:

```
pub fn element(count: i32, name: &str) -> Element<> {
    let equ: Element = Element { count: count, name: name.to_string() };
    return equ
}
```

Easy! Now the function handles the stringing for me! what joy!.. except that now when something is already a string, and I want to add it to an element, like, I don't know, **every single non unit test implementation of this function?**, I have to turn it into an &str.

Seeing as avoiding this sort of thing was the whole purpose of this venture in the first place, I started looking for ways to fix it, but I just couldn't find anything. Traits looked promising, but I can't pass in arguments the way I want to. I saw something about defining multiple functions, but I can't seem to get it to work. Defining an enum *would* work, but that forces me to wrap the input string in the enum, which is more work than just .to_string(), which defeats the whole purpose.

Thanks in advance for the help! and please tell me if any clarification is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting a `String` to `&str` is as simple as adding an ampresand: `&string`. I don't think this justifies a change.

However, if you are concerned with the performance of cloning the string unnecessarily, you can take `impl Into<String>` (that accepts both `String` and `&str`) and turn it into `String` via `.into()`:

```rust
pub fn element(count: i32, name: impl Into<String>) -> Element {
    Element { count, name: name.into() }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! looking at it now i dont see why I assumed they were different data types (instead of just a reference vs the actual value), but this solution works great!

Comment: @Majestic_Monkey_ `&String` and `&str` [are slightly different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-string-vec-or-box-as-a-function) but there is a bit of deref coercion magic. That might be the reason why you thought they were.